# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to download db data in excel format but when I click on download then it says:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()

**Controller**

```php
function excel()
{
    $pdf_data = DB::table('importpdfs')->toArray();
    $pdf_array[] = array('Battery', 'No_of_questions_attempted', 'SAS', 'NPR', 'ST', 'GR');

    foreach ($pdf_data as $pdf) {
        $pdf_array[] = array(
            'Battery'                   => $pdf->Battery,
            'No_of_questions_attempted' => $pdf->No_of_questions_attempted,
            'SAS'                       => $pdf->SAS,
            'NPR'                       => $pdf->NPR,
            'ST'                        => $pdf->ST,
            'GR'                        => $pdf->GR
        );
    }

    Excel::download('Pdf Data', function ($excel) use ($pdf_array) {
        $excel->setTitle('Pdf Data');
        $excel->sheet('Pdf Data', function ($sheet) use ($pdf_array) {
            $sheet->fromArray($pdf_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `toArray` on the query builder, you have to load the data first and then call `toArray` on the collection:

change

```php
$pdf_data = DB::table('importpdfs')->toArray();
```

to

```php
$pdf_data = DB::table('importpdfs')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: now it says:  Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of the type string, object given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\webpro3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237

Comment: The first argument of `Excel::download` has to be an instance of your Exportclass, the second argument is the filename, you cannot pass a closure to it. Check out the [quick start guide](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/).